# How to Refactor Common These Shortcut Keys

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring

During the initial development of my .NET application (using WinForms), I had to go in and create common editing shortcuts such as CTRL-A, CTRL-C, and CTRL-V because they are not enabled by default.  Now that my application has grown to quite a few text boxes, I am trying to figure out how to refactor the following code.  Can someone help please?

```
private void textBox1_results_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        textBox1_results.SelectAll();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }

    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        textBox1_results.Copy();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }

    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        textBox1_results.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they still needed?

Comment: What do you mean?  I just posted this question.

Comment: Maybe you create a subclass of TextBox, add and connect the KeyDown handler there and use this subclass instead of TextBox.

Comment: I know, i'm a nub.  How would you do this?  I'm still learning here.

Comment: Cut, Copy, Paste is all handled by default in the TextBox, why do you need to handle this on your own?

Comment: It's not working by default in my winforms.

Comment: You should *not* need to do this. The WinForms TextBox already supports all of the standard keyboard shortcuts (including all of those your code misses), since it's just a wrapper around the standard Windows textbox. There's no reason to handle them yourself, and in fact doing so is actively harmful. If they're not working in your project, then you have some code that is interfering with them. Consider opening a new question to get that problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
private static void Shortcut_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        textBox.SelectAll();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }

    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        textBox.Copy();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }

    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        textBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

And apply it:

```
textBox1.KeyDown += Shortcut_KeyDown;
textBox2.KeyDown += Shortcut_KeyDown;
// etc...
```

Although I'm not sure why you would need to write this at all - this behavior is standard to Winforms TextBox as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you....that worked perfectly.  Yea, you would think so.  But all of my WinForms just DING at me and do nothing when I try to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a BaseForm that all your forms inherit from try moving the above code to it and call it from all the text box event handlers.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form1
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.TextKeyDown(sender, e);
    }
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void TextKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            ((TextBox) sender).SelectAll();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            ((TextBox)sender).Copy();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = Clipboard.GetText();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two main approaches to this.

1. Create your own text box control by inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.TextBox and adding your own implementation of the KeyDown (still calling base.KeyDown()) with the short cuts enabled
2. Create a helper class that you call in each form's Load even that iterates through all controls on the form and adds a handler to your code.

Option 1 would be something like;

```
public class ShortcutTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            SelectAll();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            Copy();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            Text = Clipboard.GetText();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Though this comes with the caveat that you'd need to replace every instance of TextBox with ShortcutTextBox.

Option two still involves refactoring but it's a once per form option. Create a helper class like the following;

```
public abstract class ControlUtilities
{
    public static void AddTextBoxShortcuts(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)c;
                txt.KeyDown += textBox_KeyDown;
            }
            else if (c.Controls != null && c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                // recursively look for text boxes
                AddTextBoxShortcuts(c.Controls);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            txt.SelectAll();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            txt.Copy();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            txt.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in your form's Load event like;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ControlUtilities.AddTextBoxShortcuts(this.Controls);
}
```